# I do not understand this error 'Syntax error on token ";", { expected after this token'

Tags: java, syntax

Currently I have the error `Syntax error on token ";", { expected after this token`, in the code shown below:

```
public class findKey {

private final static ArrayList<Integer> listofPrimes = new ArrayList<>();

//Number of Primes we want
private final static int N = 224;

for (int candidate = 2, count = 0; count < n; ++candidate) {
    if (isPrime(candidate)) {
        ++count;
        listofPrimes.add(candidate); 
    }
}

// Very Simple isPrime() Function
// Miller-Rabin Algorithm added for reference
private static boolean isPrime(int num) {

    if (num == 2 ) {
        return true;
    }
    if (num % 2 == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    for (int i = 3; i * i <= num; i += 2) {
        if (num % i == 0) return false;
    }

    return true;
}

public static int convertKey (String input) {

    int result; 
    char[] charArray = input.toCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++){
        result *= listofPrimes.get(convertInt(charArray[i]));
    }

    return result;
}

private static int convertInt (char a) {

    int ascii = (int)a; 
    int i = ascii - 32;

    return i;
}
}
```

I do not understand what the error is. I am sure it is something very stupid that I am blanking over. All help will be appreciated with this problem.

Any extra details will be answered if asked.

Comment: place your first `for` loop in a method

Comment: does the error have a line number that could help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears based on your comment

> Can for loops not exist outside a method in a class? I just started programming in Java after C

that you expect the behavior of a [`static` initializing block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html). Something like,

```
static {
    for (int candidate = 2, count = 0; count < n; ++candidate) {
        if (isPrime(candidate)) {
            ++count;
            listofPrimes.add(candidate); 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your for loop

```
for (int candidate = 2, count = 0; count < n; ++candidate) {
    if (isPrime(candidate)) {
        ++count;
        listofPrimes.add(candidate); 
    }
}
```

is not in a method.

Comment: can for loops not exist outside a method in a class? I just started programming in Java after C, so sorry if this is a bit of a newbie question